# 404 Apache tomcat in a Java project

Tags: java, html, eclipse, tomcat, post

So this is my project:

[image]

Where Registro.java is:

```
    package Ejer2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.*;



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/Registro")
public class Registro extends HttpServlet implements SingleThreadModel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    public Registro() {
        super();

    }



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session=req.getSession(true);
        Usuario miuser=(Usuario)session.getValue(session.getId());
        if(miuser==null){
            miuser=new Usuario(req.getParameter("user"),req.getParameter("password"));
            session.putValue(session.getId(),miuser);
        }
        res.setContentType("text/html");

        String user=req.getParameter("user");
        //String pass = req.getParameter("pass");

        PrintWriter toClient = res.getWriter();
        toClient.println("<html>");
        toClient.println("<title>REGISTRO REALIZADO</title>");
        toClient.println("Usuario "+user+" registrado con exito");
        toClient.println("</html>");

        toClient.close();
    }

}
```

And registro.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Registro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/Ejer2/Registro" method="POST">
            <input type=hidden name=registro value=resultadoRegistro>
            <BR><BR>Username: <input type=text name=user>
            <BR><BR>Password: <input type=password name=pass>
            <BR><BR><input type=submit value="Enviar"><input type=reset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run registro.html everything goes as expected:

[image]

But when I enter an username and a password it doesnt work:

[image][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgWJ1.png)

It seems as if it doesnt find the Registro.java. I have tried changing the `action="/Ejer2/Registro"` to many other things like just `/Registro` orthe full `http://...` but still doesnt work.

This is my web.xml:

[image]

What can be the problem?

Comment: show me your web.xml file

Comment: @MartinČuka Done, in the question

Comment: I need to see source code of your web.xml. Change from "design" to "source"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are missing servlet mapping in your web.xml. You need to register your servlet in web.xml (open web.xml file and at the bottom change tab to see actual source code not designer) add following code and you should be good to go

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegistroServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Ejer2.Registro</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegistroServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Registro</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also suggest you to step back and start with basic java before attemping to write web application. You have several newbie issueses with your code:
1) name of packages should start with lower case !
2) also url mapping should be with lower case like this /registro

in your form action change url to match urlmapping. In your case it's
form action="/Registro" ...
Ejer2 is name of package it has nothing to do with url mapping. Hope it helps to resolve your problem